# Clicking on same li slideup is not working properly

Tags: jquery

Clicking on same li slideup is not working properly.

```
jQuery(".left_navigation ul li li, .subnav_title").live('click', function (event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    })
    jQuery(".left_navigation ul li").live('click', function (){ 
      jQuery(".left_navigation ul li").removeClass("active");  
      jQuery(".sub_nav").slideUp("50");
      jQuery(this).find(".sub_nav").stop(true, true).slideToggle("50"); 
      jQuery(this).addClass("active");
      jQuery(".left_navigation ul li a").removeClass("active"); 
      jQuery(this).children("a").addClass("active"); 

    });
```

here you'll find code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajoshi13/dsp6X/4/)

Comment: Clicking on same li slideup is not working properly, here you'll find code on jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ajoshi13/dsp6X/4/

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are using slide toggle which means it will open when closed and close when opened. But you also had

```
jQuery(".sub_nav").stop(true, true).slideUp("fast");
```

So effectivly you where sliding up then toggling which opens it again

Remove that and everything seems to work.

See
http://jsfiddle.net/dsp6X/5/

Comment: But if i remove it then auto close will not work.
i want that when we click on any li then the present .sub_nav should be close.....

Answer (score 0):

Update your line of code:

```
jQuery(this).find(".sub_nav").stop(true, true).slideToggle("50");
```

to this:

```
jQuery(this).find(".sub_nav").stop(true, false).slideToggle("50");
```